# How do I add a trendline with categories to HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, regression

With datasource expressed as X,Y the trendline appears correctly. However, things dont work with categories. Is there a good way to add a timeline without reformatting the data?

JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/9r9ba64r/5/

```
$(function () {

    // series data with Y and categories (this doesnt work!)
    //var sourceData = [{y:100} , {y:200}, {y:300}, {y:400}];    
    var categories = ['18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '21-Jul-14'];

    // series data X and Y (this works!)
    var sourceData = [[0, 99.75], [1, 99.77], [2,150]];

        $('#container').highcharts({
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories
            },
             series: [{
                name: 'RNA - CP ( Radio Network Availability - Customer Perceived)',
                data: sourceData
            },{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'trend',
                data: (function() {
                  return fitData(sourceData).data;
                })()
            }]
      });
});
```

Should I be using a different plugins like these [plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/22/Highcharts%20regression)?

Any help would be awesome. Thank you very much!

Edit: 
Fixed the jsfiddle

Comment: did you mean "trendline"? You used the word "timeline"

Comment: Fiddle link is correct? Code in question is different.

Comment: All data is x,y - you just need to know what x means in your data. In the case of categories, it's the array index of the category. So you need to express the data of your trend line in the same manner (ie, if you're using categories, don't feed your regression function dates, feed it the [0-n] x values that the chart will use).

Answer (score 2):

fitData() function that you are using doesn't support this format of data. When x axis is category data should be array of numbers (e.g. `var sourceData = [100,200,300,400];`)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t2tc93zh/

Source for plugin: http://rawgit.com/virtualstaticvoid/highcharts_trendline/master/regression.js

Comment: Are there trendlines that would be flexible for those datasets? Do you have experience with http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/22/Highcharts%20regression? THANKS!

Comment: @John Mcdock That plugin also does not support your data format. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t2tc93zh/1/ So, you have 4 options: 1) look for another plugin 2) adapt existing plugin to work with your data 3) develop new logic for trendline 4) process your data, so acceptable format is used

Comment: For anyone wondering the fitData() function is absolutely perfect for retrieving the trend line data back to you in an array. Just console.log(fitData(x)) the data that you have. It worked in my favor for multiple uses.